# Buttons not on same height as rest of row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an upload layout that contains a box with a row inside of it. The row has two `buttons` (with inputs wrapped inside them) and one `h3`. I cannot get them to stay on the same height. The following code illustrates this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mi-wrap">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="inner-wrap">
            <div id="wide-bar">
                <button id="upload-button">
                <input type="file" id="upload" value="PDF"/>
                </button>
                <h3 id="file-preview"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Upload je bestand</h3>
                <button id="send-button" type="submit" name="search-button">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#mi-wrap {
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto 0;
  height:200px;
}

#main-wrap {
    background-color:blue;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto 0;
    height:100%;
}

#inner-wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:table;
}

#wide-bar {
    height:60px;
}

#wide-bar button, #wide-bar h3 {
  background-color: green;
  height:60px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#wide-bar button {
  width:25px;
}

#wide-bar button input {
  display:none;
}

#wide-bar h3 {
  width:50%;
}
```

The code is not finished (i.e. it is not exactly the same as my own), but it does illustrate the problem. [Also in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89u30vhx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put another display, as `inline-block` combined with `vertical-align`

```
#wide-bar h3 {
  width:50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/89u30vhx/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
#wide-bar button, #wide-bar h3 {
    background-color: green;
    border: 0 none;
    /*display: table-cell;*/ /*Remove this property*/
    float: left;/*Add this property*/
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [Custom message from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11314312)

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
#wide-bar {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height:60px;
    display:table;
}

#wide-bar button, #wide-bar h3 {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color: green;
  display:table-cell
}

#wide-bar button {
  width:25px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css as follows:

```
#wide-bar {
    height: 60px;
}

#wide-bar button, #wide-bar h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/badge2033/89u30vhx/2/)